# Правильно ли предложение? (1)

Tags: грамотная-речь

"В процессе таких уголовных дел достаточно трудно установить причину смерти больного и выявить, могло бы иное лечение предотвратить летальный исход".

Answer (score 3):

Предложение не совсем правильно.

1. Часть предложения после запятой подходит только для вопросительного предложения. Чтобы исправить эту часть, можно либо заменить "**бы**" на "**ли**", либо дополнить её в конце альтернативой "**или нет**".
2. Обращает на себя внимание "*в процессе... дела*". "Процесс (чего-то)" предполагает действие, выраженное этим "чем-то". Это может быть отглагольное существительное, однако "дело" в качестве такого существительного не подходит, поскольку уголовные дела не "делают", а "ведут" или "расследуют". Можно напр. "**в процессе расследования**":

> В процессе *расследования* таких уголовных дел *сравнительно* трудно
>   установить причину смерти больного и выявить, могло бы иное лечение
>   предотвратить летальный исход *или нет*.

"Достаточно" лучше заменить, иначе возникает вопрос: достаточно трудно для чего - чтобы пожаловаться на трудности и бросить дело?

Comment: Думаю, "достаточно" здесь  употреблено вместо "довольно" (довольно трудно). По-моему, это ошибка, и ошибка распостраненная. Хотель бы узнать Ваше менение (ошибка ли и насколько распространенная).

Comment: Это не очень серьёзная ошибка, скорее канцелярский штамп, допускающий двусмысленность. Смысл, который хотят передать: "достаточно" трудно для того, чтобы назвать это словом "трудно". "Довольно" передаёт этот смысл более однозначно, изменяя степень "трудности". Видимо, этого слова пытаются избежать в "строгих" текстах из-за некоторого оттенка неуверенности: "довольно" ассоциируется с "пожалуй" и т. п. Явной же ошибкой являются выражения вроде "достаточно мало".